# presto No factory for connector mysql

Tags: presto

I clone presto from github and build the project. But when I tried to run PrestoServer, an exception was thrown as java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No factory for connector mysql. The detailed output as follow:

> > 2014-12-10T16:48:31.617+0800     INFO   main    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  Logging initialized @12338ms
> >     2014-12-10T16:48:32.117+0800   WARN   main    io.airlift.jmx.JmxAgent Cannot
> >     determine if JMX agent is already running (not an Oracle JVM?). Will
> >     try to start it manually. 2014-12-10T16:48:33.024+0800
> >     INFO  main    io.airlift.jmx.JmxAgent JMX agent started and listening on
> >     lin-virtual-machine:35776
> >     2014-12-10T16:48:34.073+0800  ERROR   Discovery-0 io.airlift.discovery.client.CachingServiceSelector  Cannot
> >     connect to discovery server for refresh (collector/general): Lookup of
> >     collector failed for http://myhost.com:8080/v1/service/collector/general
> >     2014-12-10T16:48:34.112+0800  ERROR   Discovery-2 io.airlift.discovery.client.CachingServiceSelector  Cannot
> >     connect to discovery server for refresh (presto/general): Lookup of
> >     presto failed for http://myhost.com:8080/v1/service/presto/general
> >     2014-12-10T16:48:46.273+0800
> >     INFO  main    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
> >     2014-12-10T16:48:46.288+0800
> >     WARN  main    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler    No Server
> >     set for org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler@4f6a5cc9
> >     2014-12-10T16:48:55.883+0800
> >     INFO  main    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started
> >     o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@420dde28{/,null,AVAILABLE,@http}
> >     2014-12-10T16:48:56.001+0800
> >     INFO  main    org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector    Started
> >     http@712213ed{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080} 2014-12-10T16:48:56.002+0800
> >     INFO  main    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server Started @36725ms
> >     2014-12-10T16:48:57.102+0800
> >     INFO  Discovery-3 io.airlift.discovery.client.CachingServiceSelector  Discovery
> >     server connect succeeded for refresh (collector/general)
> >     2014-12-10T16:48:57.116+0800
> >     INFO  Discovery-0 io.airlift.discovery.client.CachingServiceSelector  Discovery
> >     server connect succeeded for refresh (presto/general)
> >     2014-12-10T16:48:57.958+0800
> >     INFO  main    io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager   Life cycle starting...
> >     2014-12-10T16:48:57.958+0800
> >     INFO  main    io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager   Life cycle startup
> >     complete. System ready. 2014-12-10T16:48:57.959+0800
> >     INFO  main    com.facebook.presto.metadata.CatalogManager -- Loading
> >     catalog /home/lin/presto-server-0.86/etc/catalog/mysql.properties --
>
> 2014-12-10T16:48:57.973+0800  ERROR   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer No
>   factory for connector mysql java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No
>   factory for connector mysql   at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145)
>   ~[jar:rsrc:guava-18.0.jar!/:na]   at
>   com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnection(ConnectorManager.java:97)
>   ~[rsrc:./:na]     at
>   com.facebook.presto.metadata.CatalogManager.loadCatalog(CatalogManager.java:88)
>   ~[rsrc:./:na]     at
>   com.facebook.presto.metadata.CatalogManager.loadCatalogs(CatalogManager.java:70)
>   ~[rsrc:./:na]     at
>   com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.run(PrestoServer.java:108)
>   [rsrc:./:na]  at
>   com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.main(PrestoServer.java:60)
>   [rsrc:./:na]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_25]    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
>   [presto-main.jar:na] 2014-12-10T16:48:57.977+0800
>
> INFO  Thread-142  io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager   Life cycle
>   stopping...

Comment: I also have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
After viewing logs , got the issue.
In properties file I was passing "mysql " instead of "mysql".
It doesn't trim properties data.